# MetaException(message:MetaException(message:java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hbase

I am facing this issue when creating external table from Hive to HBase.
I am using Hadoop 3.2.2, Hive 2.3.8 and HBase 2.3.4 with JDK 11.0.
I start hadoop and HBase, and all service (
HMaster,
RegionServer,
Zookeeper, etc) are running fine.
But getting this error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:MetaException(message:java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:413)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:125)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:747)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:740)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:852)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:867)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4356)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Constructor threw an exception for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:48)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(ConnectionManager.java:637)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:46)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ClassSize
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.(IPCUtil.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.(AbstractRpcClient.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.(RpcClientImpl.java:1072)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.(RpcClientImpl.java:1098)
... 53 more
)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:129)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:747)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:740)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:852)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:867)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4356)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
)

Comment: Maybe you can share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: added please check